# How to help counter picked top lane as a jungler?

Tags: league-of-legends

If the top lane gets hard counter picked, how can the jungler help top laner gain an early advantage?

For example, is it worth it to skip creep camps within the first 5 minutes in order to gank and kill the opposing top laner?

Answer (score 5):

If your top was hard counterpicked, my suggestion would be:

```
* Get a HARD leash on your first buff camp (strong enough that you keep Smite 
    but still gain a Level); Start with the one furthest from your Top lane 
    (Red Buff if you're on Blue Team, Blue if you're on Purple)
* Immediately RUSH to your next buff and kill it  with Smite. Make sure you use
    your Pots and are at 3/4 HP or better!
* Immediately RUSH to top lane to gank. You will be at Level 3, 
    and if you are a fast enough jungler, the top lane will be just about to 
    ding Level 2. A gank this early is usually devastating. If you can wrangle
    it so your Top Laner gets the kill, the gank was perfectly successful.
```

After all of that, have your Top Laner stick close to turret and ward his Tribrush and right in front of the Baron pit. This will give enough time to evade possible ganks, and the farming in front of tower leaves the other Teams' Top wide open for ganks.

Gank top about 150% more often than you normally would. This is known as "Camping a lane".

Allow your Top Laner to take your wolves (if on Blue Side) or Small Golems (if on Purple) to get some EXP advantage over the other team Pre-Lane. Help him out with them so he doesn't take too much damage, but make sure he gets the EXP! This provides about 1/2 the EXP required to reach Lv. 2.

Make sure to stress to him how important it is to passively farm WHENEVER possible in lane; Then, when you gank, that he needs to let you initiate but STILL NEEDS TO SMACK THEM IN THE FACE A FEW TIMES! Remind them that even though they got counterpicked, if they get themselves fed (with your help), they basically become uncountered again.

If your Top Laner is unresponsive or unhelpful after these tips and suggestions, then let him be and help your Carry Lanes get fed. Play around him strategically and you can still pull off a win. If the Enemy Top Lane is fed, but the rest of YOUR team is fed, you still can win.

Do your best to give your Mid Champ the Blue buff whenever it comes back up, and to deny the other Mid the chance to get THEIR Blue! If you force the other jungler to smite-steal it, then you did good. (This may not seem like it would help out Top at all, but trust me: getting Mid any sort of advantage over their lane means that they can start roaming and help out Top and Bot sooner, which means more help for you and an easier  chance at winning the mid game.)

ALso, ALWAYS REMEMBER: Prioritize Towers and Map Objectives over Kills.

One Tower = 150 Gold per Champion. This equates to 750 Gold for the team. That's more gold than a Legendary Kill streak ending! one or two champions dying for a tower is okay, but not optimal.

Dragon = 190 Gold per Champion, PLUS Last-Hit gold (40 gold) AND global EXP for the team. 1,000 gold total if a Masteried Smite was used. If a tower goes down mid-fight, you still come out on top.

And finally - do your utmost to make sure the kills from your ganks are spread around as much as possible amongst your team members. Share the wealth! You want everyone a little fed, not one or two a lot fed. (A little secret: Supports may not be supposed to get kills, but a fed Support (2-4 kills by late game) is a SCARY thing indeed!)

Hope this helps!

--ccreason

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on who you're jungling as. As olaf (or anyone as fast as him) I will kill blue, wolves, red and gank immediately if the opportunity is there.

Red gives a giant advantage in you're ganking - the slow on it early can determine the enemy escaping or just barely landing that last hit. Making use of it early gives you more opportunities to gank with it.

If you're a slow jungler, however, you are only hurting yourself and the team. If enemy jungle pops out early and I can't prevent a gank/they won't succesfully gank, best believe I will steal your jungle and screw you over.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on which champion you are playing. If you are playing a hyper aggressive jungler (such as Lee Sin or Alistar), you can get away with camping top and helping your lane. If not, you might be better off helping the other two lanes and carry the top lane. If your top lane starts asking for ganks when you're getting a lot of kills middle or bottom, mute him instantly.  Helping top will only take pressure off the other lanes; just let him lose and carry him later.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to skip camps to pressure top as a jungler. You merely apply pressure inbetween camp spawns. As an example, suppose you know you want to babysit top because it was severely counterpicked by the enemy. You can start wraiths into red, then you have a choice. Gank top, force a summoner, apply pressure, potentially give your top some dominance just by making your presence known, or do golems. Golems are done, you have another choice. Gank top again, or do wraiths. To babysit/apply pressure, repeat this pattern of jungle camp-gank-jungle camp-gank. Note that in the end, you want to use your best judgement, and sometimes it will not be appropriate to gank, but I should say, as a 1700 player, most lower level players tend to think a lane is not gankable when this is simply not true.

Answer (score 0):

I mainly play the jungle, and i look for ganks for the lanes who most need it. or as you said the lanes that get counter picked the worst. you still need to stay ahead of the enemy jungle so farm your jungle. you just need to tell your top lane to let then push far enough to overextend and make sure they are ready to kill their counter pick. it really depends on tho you jungle as well. lee sin can gank lvl 2 right after red buff, as a maokai should do it at lvl 4ish after he has blue and his root ability.

Answer (score 0):

I would rather not skip camps since if you do you lost exp to try to gank. Skipping those camps would cause you to be lower level causing a lower chance of a successful gank. I would just prioritize the lane. Whenever you are ready to gank go gank top. I've had a situation like this, but it was mid lane. I never ganked another lane until I pretty much shutdown the AP carry. After I continued normally jungling ganking other lanes. Your ganks can be the heart of why your team was victorious. So prioritizing the lane may actually help you to stop "fed" opposing top laner.

Answer (score 0):

I read somewhere that Top lane is the highest priority lane to gank. Top > Mid> Bot > Their jungle. Being the reason for Top and mid, if you get the gank or even just shut them down, your top/mid lane will have more money and just snowball over their opponent.

Answer (score 0):

On most junglers, you should try to start at the buff thats close to top alne (depending on which site you are) and gank top at lvl 2, just to give him an advantage. then you grab the other buff and gank again. You can help him by getting him an early ward as well. If you figure you guys have no kill potential top at all, just focus on mid and bot and try to get enough global objectives(dragons, towers). If mid gets ahead enough, mid can gank top as well.